# Mysql Pivot Table group by two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot-table

I am having issue while creating pivot table using Mysql.

Actual query is as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT `bills_organization`.`name`,
        IF(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=1,COUNT(`bills_bill`.`os_status`),NULL) AS Unnknown,
        IF(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=2,COUNT(`bills_bill`.`os_status`),NULL) AS Introduced,
        IF(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=3,COUNT(`bills_bill`.`os_status`),NULL) AS Passedonechamber,
        IF(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=4,COUNT(`bills_bill`.`os_status`),NULL) AS Passedbothchambers,
        IF(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=5,COUNT(`bills_bill`.`os_status`),NULL) AS Enacted
FROM `bills_mybill` 
INNER JOIN `auth_user` ON (`bills_mybill`.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bills_bill` ON (`bills_mybill`.`bill_id` = `bills_bill`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bills_userprofile` ON (`auth_user`.`id` = `bills_userprofile`.`user_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bills_organization` ON (`bills_userprofile`.`organization_id` = `bills_organization`.`id`) 
WHERE `bills_mybill`.`favorite` = TRUE  
GROUP BY `bills_organization`.`name`,`bills_bill`.`os_status`
```

This output as follows

```
name   Unnknown   Introduced   Passedonechamber   Passedbothchambers   Enacted
NUL    NULL       5            NULL               NULL                 NULL
NULL   NULL       NULL         NULL               1                    NULL
AEE    NULL       16           NULL               NULL                 NULL
AEE    NULL       NULL         1                  NULL                 NULL
AEE    NULL       NULL         NULL              4                     NULL
AEE    NULL       NULL         NULL              NULL                  2
Testing NULL      6            NULL              NULL                  NULL
Testing NULL      NULL         NULL              2                     NULL
Testing NULL      NULL         NULL              NULL                  6
```

I want organization and there count in one line. I don't want in multiple rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Pivot + Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561881/mysql-pivot-counting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `bills_organization`.`name`,
        SUM(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=1) AS Unnknown,
        SUM(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=2) AS Introduced,
        SUM(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=3) AS Passedonechamber,
        SUM(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=4) AS Passedbothchambers,
        SUM(`bills_bill`.`os_status`=5) AS Enacted
FROM `bills_mybill` 
INNER JOIN `auth_user` ON (`bills_mybill`.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bills_bill` ON (`bills_mybill`.`bill_id` = `bills_bill`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bills_userprofile` ON (`auth_user`.`id` = `bills_userprofile`.`user_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bills_organization` ON (`bills_userprofile`.`organization_id` = `bills_organization`.`id`) 
WHERE `bills_mybill`.`favorite` = TRUE  
GROUP BY `bills_organization`.`name`
```