# Should I use excel or create my own pivot query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

My attendance table has the following fields:

```
attendance 
  studentID, 
  cDate, 
  isPresent
```

The isPresent field contains 1 for present, 0 for absent.

I need a pivot query for final attendance report that will have header

```
studentID, date1, date2, date3..., total
```

and each data row will contain something like:

```
St001, 1,1,0,1... 3
```

date1, date2 etc. will be found from the data.

Now I am exporting the data into an excel file for the report.

But I want to do it in MySQL.

Can anyone help me on creating the pivot query.

I read many articles on it but with not much clear conception.

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is.

Comment: see my answer hw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711642/mysql-mariadb-create-a-pivot-table-view/62712027#62712027 and try to adapt it to your needs if tít doesn't work

Comment: Very easy with excel, don't complicate! Or write some code to do the logic. Still you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561881/mysql-pivot-counting to do it in MySQL!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stored procedure that will create the pivot code and execute it:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot