# How to count values ​on a pivot table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-framework, phpmyadmin

I have two tables **Users** and **Get_cal** like below :

**Users**

| id_user(pk) | com |
| --- | --- |
| 1004 | 700 |
| 1005 | 700 |
| 1006 | 700 |
| 1010 | 701 |
| 1011 | 701 |
| 1012 | 701 |
| 1013 | 701 |
| 1014 | 800 |
| 1015 | 800 |
| 1016 | 800 |
| 1017 | 800 |

**Get_cal**

| id_user(fk) | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1004 | ABAN |
| 1004 | ABAN |
| 1004 | DES |
| 1004 | LET |
| 1004 | DES |
| 1004 | ABAN |
| 1011 | LET |
| 1011 | LET |
| 1011 | ABAN |
| 1015 | ABAN |
| 1015 | DES |
| 1015 | LET |
| 1015 | LET |

For **status** column I have **5 types (ABAN,DES,LET,NOANS,OTH)**.
I want to get this result like below(**Get the count by user by status** ):

| id_user | ABAN | DES | LET | NOANS | OTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1005 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1006 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1010 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1011 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1012 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1013 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1014 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1015 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1016 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1017 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I have no idea how to start the query, please any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Pivot + Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561881/mysql-pivot-counting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    u.id_user,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 'ABAN'  THEN 1 END) AS ABAN,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 'DES'   THEN 1 END) AS DES,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 'LET'   THEN 1 END) AS LET,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status = 'NOANS' THEN 1 END) AS NOANS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status NOT IN ('ABAN', 'DES', 'LET', 'NOAN')
               THEN 1 END) AS OTH
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Get_cal c
    ON c.id_user = u.id_user
GROUP BY
    u.id_user
ORDER BY
    u.id_user;
```

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN c.status NOT IN ('ABAN', 'DES', 'LET', 'NOAN') THEN 1 END) AS OTH`  OP does not tell that the value in the column cannot be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If your status is always static with that 5 cases. you can use `left join` and `group by` and some switch case conditions to solve the query.

```
SELECT Users.id_user ,
SUM(CASE WHEN Get_cal.status = 'ABAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABAN ,
SUM(CASE WHEN Get_cal.status = 'DES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DES ,
SUM(CASE WHEN Get_cal.status = 'LET' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LET ,
SUM(CASE WHEN Get_cal.status = 'NOANS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NOANS ,
SUM(CASE WHEN Get_cal.status = 'OTH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OTH 
FROM Users LEFT JOIN Get_cal ON (Users.id_user = Get_cal.id_user) GROUP BY Users.id_user ,Get_cal.id_user
```