# How to seperate an enum-value column to each value a bool column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, logstash, pivot-table

I have a table:

```
+-----------+----------+
| articleId | category |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | life     |
|         1 | game     |
|         2 | tech     |
|         3 | life     |
|       ... | ...      |
+-----------+----------+
```

Now I have to downgrade the paradigms of data, make them be flat and wide. Because they will be fed into an analysis enviroment which has no such data relationships. (actually, it's Elasticsearch)

Finally the selected data must be like this:

```
+-----------+------+------+------+
| articleId | game | life | tech |
+-----------+------+------+------+
|         1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
|         2 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|         3 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
|       ... |      |      |      |
+-----------+------+------+------+
```

Could you tell me how I can do that?

---

The categories field is enumrable, I can manually create each column.

Comment: This is called a "Pivot". Check out the excepted answer at this question: [MySQL: Pivot + Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561881/mysql-pivot-counting)

Comment: @JNevill Thanks. I'm poor at English. Sorry about it. I will continue to study on this basis

Comment: No worries. It's common for people that haven't encountered "pivot" before to not know the word for it. There's at least one question each day on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` your `articleId` and check if your data exists:

```
SELECT t.`articleId`,
SUM(t.`category`='game') game,
SUM(t.`category`='life') life,
SUM(t.`category`='tech') tech
FROM test_test t 
GROUP BY t.`articleId`
```

`t.category='someText'` will either return you 0 or 1 and then using `SUM` will give you your desired result.